# How do I run function on database class rather than class in views.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have this in my views.py, it all works if I use the class in the views.py but if i switch the function to use the same class in the models.py (which is what I want to use) I get:
'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'DeferredAttribute'

If I declare it an int() then I get:
a typerror. int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

This is my code. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import math, datetime
from settings.models import Extruder

class Extruders:
    def __init__(self, name, min_width = 0, max_width = 0, max_speed = 0, gussets = False, printer = False, 
                 location = "GY", lft = False, cfs = False, dws = False, jfs = False, sws = False, treatment = False):
        self.name = name
        self.min_width = min_width
        self.max_width = max_width
        self.max_speed = max_speed
        self.gussets = gussets
        self.printer = printer
        self.location = location
        self.lft = lft
        self.cfs = cfs
        self.dws = dws
        self.jfs = jfs
        self.sws = sws
        self.treatment = treatment
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

ext1 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 1", max_width = 300, min_width = 50, max_speed= 30, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True, treatment = True)
ext2 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 2", max_width = 300, min_width = 40, max_speed= 30, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext3 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 3", max_width = 600, min_width = 200, max_speed= 30, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext4 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 4", max_width = 800, min_width = 400, max_speed= 70, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext5 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 5", max_width = 300, min_width = 50, max_speed= 30, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext6 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 6", max_width = 300, min_width = 100, max_speed= 30, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext7 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 7", max_width = 400, min_width = 200, max_speed= 70, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True)
ext8 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 8", max_width = 1020, min_width = 500, max_speed= 130, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True, treatment = True, sws = True, jfs = True)
ext9 = Extruders(name = "Extruder 9", max_width = 1550, min_width = 800, max_speed= 160, 
                     gussets = True, printer = True, location = "GY", lft = True, cfs = True, dws = True, sws = True, treatment = True, jfs = True)

ext = [
    ext1, ext2, ext3, ext4, ext5, ext6, ext7, ext8, ext9
]

extruders =  Extruder.objects.all()


class FilmSpeedView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'calculations/film-speed.html'

class BagWeightView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'calculations/bag-weight.html'

class CalculatorsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'calculations/calculators.html'

def filmSpeed(request):
    return render(request, 'calculations/film-speed.html')

def result(request):
    film_type=''
    film_width=''
    measure=''
    speeds = [0]
    quantity = 0
    max_speed = 0
    ave_speed = 0
    ave_time = 0
    max_time = 0
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c=[]
    d=[]
    e=[]
    if request.method=="GET":
        film_type = str(request.GET["film_type"])
        film_width = int(request.GET["film_width"])
        edge_trim = int(request.GET["edge_trim"])
        quantity =int(request.GET["quantity"])
        measure = str(request.GET["measure"])
        if measure == "metric":
            film_width = int(film_width)
        else:
            film_width = film_width * 25.4
        if edge_trim == '':
            edge_trim = 0
        else:
            edge_trim = int(edge_trim)
        if str(film_type) == 'Layflat Tubing':
            film_type = "LFT"
            for extruder in extruders:
                if film_width < int(Extruder.min_width):
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Film too narrow')
                elif film_width > int(Extruder.max_width):
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Film too wide')
                else:
                    percentage = film_width / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = Extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    a.append(Extruder.name + ' : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kgs/h')
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    max_speed = max(speeds)
                    ave_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
                    ave_time = float(quantity) / ave_speed * 60.0
                    max_time = float(quantity) / max_speed * 60.0
        elif film_type == "Single Wound Sheeting":
            film_type = "SWS"
            for extruder in extruders:
                if film_width < Extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : too narrow for extruder')
                elif film_width > Extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Too wide for extruder')
                else:
                    percentage = (film_width + edge_trim) / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = Extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    a.append(Extruder.name + ' : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
                    max_speed = max(speeds)
                    ave_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
                    ave_time = float(quantity) / ave_speed * 60.0
                    max_time = float(quantity) / max_speed * 60.0
                if math.floor(Extruder.max_width / (film_width + edge_trim)) >= 2:
                    number_up = math.floor(Extruder.min_width / (film_width + edge_trim))
                    extrusion_width = film_width * number_up
                    percentage = extrusion_width / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = percentage * Extruder.max_speed
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    c.append(Extruder.name + ' : can run this film ' + str(number_up) + ' up and ')
                   
        elif film_type == "Double Wound Sheeting":
            film_type = "DWS"
            for extruder in extruders:
                if film_width + (edge_trim * 2) < Extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Too narrow for extruder')
                elif film_width + (edge_trim * 2) > Extruder.max_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Too wide for extruder')
                else:
                    extrusion_width = (edge_trim * 2) + film_width
                    percentage = Extrusion_width / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    a.append(Extruder.name + ' : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h - film width ' + str(film_width + (edge_trim * 2)) + 'mm')
                    max_speed = max(speeds)
                    ave_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
                    ave_time = float(quantity) / ave_speed * 60.0
                    max_time = float(quantity) / max_speed * 60.0
                if math.floor(Extruder.max_width / (film_width + (edge_trim * 2))) >= 2:
                    number_up = math.floor(Extruder.max_width / (film_width + (edge_trim * 2)))
                    c.append('This can run ' + str(number_up) + ' up')

                else:
                    print('Not Within ' + Extruder.name + '\'s capabilities')
            
        elif film_type == "J-Fold Sheeting":
            film_type = "JFS"
            for extruder in extruders:
                if film_width < Extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Too narrow for extruder')
                elif film_width > Extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(Extruder.name + ' : Too wide for extruder')
                else:
                    percentage = film_width / Extruder.min_width
                    speed = Extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    a.append(Extruder.name + ' : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
                    max_speed = max(speeds)
                    ave_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
                    ave_time = float(quantity) / ave_speed * 60.0
                    max_time = float(quantity) / max_speed * 60.0
                if film_width - float(strip_out) * 2 < extruder.min_width:
                    extrusion_width = (film_width - strip_out) * 2
                    percentage = Extrusion_width / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = Extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    c.append(Extruder.name + ' : Can run this film 2 up Staggered at ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
                else:
                    c.append("Too wide for 2 up")
                if (film_width * 2) < Extruder.max_width:
                    percentage = (film_width * 2) / Extruder.max_width
                    speed = Extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    d.append(Extruder.name + ' : Can run this film with strip out at ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
                    strip_out_percent = (strip_out * 2) / (film_width * 2)
                    strip_out_weight = float(qty) * float(strip_out_percent)
                    strip_out = ("{}  : Strip out scrap weight will be:  {}  kg\'s").format(Extruder.name, round(strip_out_weight, 2))
                    e.append(Extruder.name + ' : Strip out = ' + str(strip_out_percent * 100) + '%')
                    
        elif film_type == "Gussetted Layflat Tubing":
            film_type = "GLFT"


            
        elif film_type == "Centrefold Sheeting":
            film_type = "CFS"
            for extruder in extruders:
            # Check the width is ok and then check if film can be run 2 up on extruder.
                if film_width < extruder.min_width:
                    b.append(extruder.name + ' : Too narrow for extruder')
                elif film_width > extruder.max_width:
                    b.append(extruder.name + ' : Too wide for extruder')
                else:
                    percentage = film_width / extruder.max_width
                    speed = extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    c.append(extruder.name + ' : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
                    max_speed = max(speeds)
                    ave_speed = sum(speeds) / len(speeds)
                    ave_time = float(quantity) / ave_speed * 60.0
                    max_time = float(quantity) / max_speed * 60.0

            # Check if film can be run 2 up
                if film_width * 2 < extruder.max_width:
                    percentage = (film_width * 2) / extruder.max_width
                    speed = extruder.max_speed * percentage
                    speeds.append(speed)
                    d.append(extruder.name + ' 2 up : ' + str(round(speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h')
        else: 
            film_type = "Invalid Film Type"


    m = a
    n = b
    o = c
    g = str(round(ave_speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h'
    h = str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=ave_time))
    i = str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=30))
    j = str(round(max_speed, 2)) + 'kg\'s/h'
    k = str(datetime.timedelta(minutes=max_time))
     

    return render(request, 'calculations/result.html', {'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d, 'e':e, 'g':g, 'h':h, 'i':i, 'j':j, 'k':k, 'm':m, 'n':n, 'o':o})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your capitalization -- you're iterating over each `extruder` but trying to access attributes of `Extruder`. Try replacing `Extruder.min_width` with `extruder.min_width` and so forth.

Comment: Thank you so much, its always something stupid!